# Custom UITableViewCell that expands on touch and includes uitextfield

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've pretty much added a lot to my CustomCell, its working great.
However, theres one thing i cant work out..

My requirement is, for a grouped TableView, On tapping a single UITableViewCell, it should expand below, kinda animate and extend below and show more information in that cell.

On tapping an already expanded cell, it should go back to a "normal" cell state.

Any direction i can have here would be great..

also, take a look at the following code, there are variables for a cell and i'm adding an image to the cell.acccessoryVIew, however, there are some examples where they write the code of adding an image within **if(cell==nil) {  }.**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellDetailSym";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CustomCell *)[[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];

    }
    cell.checkNeeded = YES;
    appdelegate *appDelegate = (appdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    customClass *nSym = (customClass *)[ArrayCache objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([appDelegate.sMap containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[nSym pKey]]]) { cell.checked=YES; } else cell.checked = NO;
    if([appDelegate.favoriteSymArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[nSym pKey]]]) { cell.starred=YES; } else cell.starred = NO;
    cell.title = nSym.txtSym;

    UIImage *starredImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star_list_active.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, starredImage.size.width + 5 , starredImage.size.height + 5);
    button.frame = frame;

    UIImage *image = (cell.starred) ? starredImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star_list_inactive.png"];
    //UIImage *newImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [button setEnabled:YES];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    return cell;

}
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to call `- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` specifying the next row down as the insertion row and animating with `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` to create the drop-down effect. To complete the cell "expansion" illusion, be sure your `separatorColor` matches your background.

Don't try calling a delegate method to resize the row height; it won't animate, as far as I can tell.